# FactoryGirl Email already taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm trying to instanciate with FactoryGirl multiple object (guests who have unique email)

```
  guests = create_list(:guest, 3)
```

But I get error :

```
 Failure/Error: guests = create_list(:guest, 3)

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

Here my factory :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :guest do
    email Faker::Internet.unique.email
    firstname 'John'
    lastname  'Doe'
    password 'test'
    password_confirmation 'test'

    factory :guest_with_bookings do
      email "#{SecureRandom.hex}@test.com"
      transient do
        bookings_count 2
      end
      after(:create) do |guest, evaluator|
        create_list(:booking, evaluator.bookings_count, guests: [guest])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Even with Faker::Internet.unique.email, it's don't working when I try to create more than 1 guest

Comment: It's seems that the answer is "sequence :email do |n|
    "person#{n}@example.com"
  end" but I don't get it

Comment: Do you clear your database between test runs?

Comment: @sergey-mell provided good answer, but actually you just forgot to use **block** `email { each_time_code }` so code `"#{SecureRandom.hex}@test.com"` executed **one** time and factory tries to create a guest with same constant email each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sequence in your factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :guest do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "name_#{n}@example.com" }
```

Or in combination with Faker

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :guest do
    sequence(:email) { |n| Faker::Internet.unique.email("Nancy_#{n}") }
```